# Will the destruction of future Universe 7 affect other timelines in 20 years?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the Black Goku arc, the future Universe 7 was destroyed by Zeno. Since Beerus said something along the lines of if a god changes an event in a timeline then it changes in all the others, does that mean that in 20 years the current Universe 7 will be destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely.

Beerus was the one that was sure that killing Zamasu was going to change future Universe 7, and it didn't change at all. So even if the destruction is done by Future Zeno it doesn't look like it would change things, specially considering that any timeline that's created makes him "less omnipotent", as all timeline counterparts of Zenos are supposed to be as strong as him.

Answer (score 3):

In Dragon Ball, when a person travels in time it creates alternative timelines/ realities. So what Beerus destroyed was an alternative timeline/reality, which has no effect in the current timeline of universe 7 therefore the current timeline wont be destroyed in the future.

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_timeline